# swift: navigationcontroller.toolbar settings

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, toolbar

I try to setup toolbar programmatically, but nothing of this works:

In AppDelegate

```
UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController?.navigationController?.toolbar.isTranslucent = false
UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController?.navigationController?.toolbar.tintColor = .black
```

In ViewDidLoad

```
navigationController?.toolbar.isTranslucent = false
navigationController?.toolbar.tintColor = .black
```

Why?

The second thing is when I navigate to another view controller, my black toolbar is shown for a moment (I hide it with navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: true)). How can I completely hide it on transitions?

Comment: Which `viewDidLoad` are you talking about? What is your view controller hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, viewDidLoad of initial view controller

Comment: *view controller next to navigationcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You could try subclassing UIViewController as in Apple's UIKitCatalog sample application. It uses the storyboard, but that might work for your project.

```
class CustomToolbarViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var toolbar: UIToolbar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let toolbarButtonItems = [
            customImageBarButtonItem
        ]
        toolbar.setItems(toolbarButtonItems, animated: true)
    }

    // MARK: - UIBarButtonItem Creation and Configuration

     var customImageBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {

     // item set up code

      }
```